# Arduino Uno wont power up when GND is plugged in Logic Converter

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

Good day.
I am trying to use an ESP8266 12e Wifi Module that requires 3.3V
I used a Logic Converter to reduce the 5v to 3.3v
My problem is when I plug the GND from the arduino to the GND on the Logic Converter, the Power On Led dies slowly on the arduino and no power at all.
When I plug the 5v only the power is back.

[image: 5v and GND both plugged]

[image: Only the 5V is plugged]

I have tried both the USB power from the laptop and a 9V 250mA power adapter but still the same result.

Any advice would really save me.

Comment: Is that soldering really as terrible as it looks?

Comment: yes. I really have no knowledge in soldering but i did my best to bind them :(

Comment: It looks like one huge blob of so solder shortcircuiting everything out.

Comment: I think you'll need an external power supply to make both of them works. ESPs need more current than arduinos.

Comment: I think you need to practice your soldering a little more. It's hard to make out, but I would say all that solder is just one huge short circuit linking the power and ground pins and risking melting your Arduino.

Comment: thank you for the enlightenment everyone. I recall that my arduino ticked and smoked a little when i plugged it using an external power source and immediately I unplugged it. It seems like my messy soldering is the culprit. I have planned to use an ESP8266 ESP-01 + adapter so i wont need to do some horrible soldering again...